# Google Charts - Need x and y value AND series

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using google charts and I'm trying to get the value of the x and y values along with the series name that a user clicks on.  I believe I have the X value by using the following in a click event.

```
console.log(dataTable.getValue(chartObject.getSelection()[0].row,0))
```

This get me the X value, but how do I get the series and Y value?  Its exactly what shows up on the hover on the point.  I just need to be able to grab these values to pass on to another function.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I've got what I wanted.

```
//X Axis
console.log(dataTable.getValue(chartObject.getSelection()[0].row,0))

//Y Axis
console.log(dataTable.getValue(chartObject.getSelection()[0].row,chartObject.getSelection()[0].column));

//Series Label
console.log(dataTable.getColumnLabel(chartObject.getSelection()[0].column))
```